# Converting xml to hierarchical data in c# with classes

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

I have a class that goes and gets data from a database and it gets the as xml data in the form of hierarchical data.

below is a sample of the data:

```
<SecurityGroups>
<SecurityGroup>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>View</Name>
</SecurityGroup>
<SecurityGroup>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Fill</Name>
    <SecurityUsers>
        <SecurityUser>
            <securityId>2</securityId>
            <userId>2</userId>
            <username>Fill</username>
        </SecurityUser>
        <SecurityUser>
            <securityId>2</securityId>
            <userId>3</userId>
            <username>FillOne</username>
        </SecurityUser>
        <SecurityUser>
            <securityId>2</securityId>
            <userId>4</userId>
        <username/></SecurityUser>
    </SecurityUsers>
</SecurityGroup>
<SecurityGroup>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Update</Name>
    <SecurityUsers>
        <SecurityUser>
            <securityId>3</securityId>
            <userId>5</userId>
            <username>Update</username>
        </SecurityUser>
        <SecurityUser>
            <securityId>3</securityId>
            <userId>6</userId>
            <username>UpdateOne</username>
        </SecurityUser>
    </SecurityUsers>
</SecurityGroup>
<SecurityGroup>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Name>Admin</Name>
    <SecurityUsers>
        <SecurityUser>
            <securityId>4</securityId>
            <userId>1</userId>
            <username>JTays</username>
        </SecurityUser>
    </SecurityUsers>
</SecurityGroup>
```

Which works great! Now, I have a class that uses reflection to convert from xml to models that i am eventually going to use in a treeview.
below is the entire class.

the models are:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class SecurityGroup
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute("SecurityUser",
        Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public List<SecurityUser> SecurityUsers { get; set; }
}

public class SecurityUser:IEntity
{
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int SecurityId { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the class that converts.

```
    public class AdminManager : IAdminService
{
    public IEnumerable<SecurityGroup> SecurityGroups()
    {
        IEnumerable<SecurityGroup> list = null;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (var c = new FMContext())
        {
            var xmlData = c.Database.SqlQuery<string>("AllSecurtyUsersProc").FirstOrDefault();
            if (xmlData != null)
            {
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);
                list = ConvertXmlToClass<SecurityGroup>(xmlDoc, "/SecurityGroups/SecurityGroup");
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ConvertXmlToClass<T>( XmlDocument doc, string nodeString)
        where T:class, new()
    {
        var xmlNodes = doc.SelectNodes(nodeString);
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
        {
            var item = GetNewItem<T>(node);
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static T GetNewItem<T>(XmlNode node)
        where T:class, new()
    {
        var type = typeof (T);
        var item = new T();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            var propertyName = property.Name;
            object value = null;
            if (IsEnumerable(property))
            {
                value = GetNodeCollectionValue(property,node);
            }
            else
            {
                value = GetNodeValue(node, propertyName);
            }
            if (value!=null)
            {
                property.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType), null);
            }

        }
        return item;
    }

    private static object GetNodeCollectionValue(PropertyInfo property, XmlNode node)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var itemType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var xml = $"<{property.Name}><{itemType.Name}>{node.InnerXml}</{itemType.Name}></{property.Name}>";
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        if (itemType != null)
        {
            var type = typeof (AdminManager);
            var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ConvertXmlToClass");
            if (methodInfo!=null)
            {
                var method = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(itemType);
                if (method != null)
                {
                    object[] args = {doc, property.Name};
                    object result = method.Invoke(null, args);
                    return result;
                }
            }

        }

        return new object();
    }


    private static bool IsEnumerable(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var type = property.PropertyType;
        return typeof (IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsGenericType;
    }

    private static object GetNodeValue(XmlNode node, string nodeName)
    {
        var i = node[nodeName]?.InnerText;
        return i ?? null;
    }
}
```

Okay, so now my issue. My problem is that when it converts it doesn't get the correct data for the `SecurtyUsers` classes it adds them as an object, but everything is null or 0. Can someone help me figure out where i went worng?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did the XML data come from in the first place? Also, why a custom deserializer instead of using the standard .NET XML serializer/deserializer? This seems like an ideal use case for that.

Comment: First the data comes from Sql Server a stored Procdure that i have written. the reason that i used this instead of entity framework was because of the several Joins and complex SQL that was required to come up with the data. the reason that i created the deserializer was because i have never used that before so i didn't know that i could.

Comment: Right, but how did the data get into SQL Server in the first place? Where did it come from, and how was it created? Who controls that process? For example, could you have them serialize their objects with a standard library like the .NET XML Serializer or the Newtonsoft JSON serializer so that you can easily deserialize it with the same library?

Answer (score 1):

First: your example XML doesn't include the closing tag `</SecurityGroups>`.

In your *GetNodeCollectionValue* you pass `property.Name` but shouldn't it be `property.Name + "/" + itemType.Name` because you want to access the children of that node?

Additionally `node.InnerXml` is not traversed, you pass the same node again and again.

I highly recommend using the .Net XML deserializer instead of reinventing the wheel.

---

[Generate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) a XML schema for your XML example. Afterwards create the .Net classes from the XSD. Pass your XML from the server to a StringReader and [Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he66c7f1(v=vs.110).aspx) using the reader. Then just access the `SecurityGroup` from the class instance.

### [update] to show usage

Create the XML Schema either manually or using the `XSD.exe` (you will need the Windows SDK). See the [Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6).

- create a *sample.xml* file, content is your example
- locate and run the XSD tool `xsd sample.xml /outputDir:XmlSerialization`
- a `.xsd` file should be generated, you may want to modify some element types

  - for example *SecurityGroup.Id* is maybe auto-generated as `xs:string`, change it to i.e. `xs:int`
  - or remove the `minOccurs="0"` at *SecurityUser.userId* if you know that the property is always set
  - you maybe have to fix *SecurityGroup.SecurityUsers* from

```xml
<xs:element name="SecurityUsers" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SecurityUser" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

to

```
<xs:element name="SecurityUsers" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SecurityUser" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

- run the XSD tool using the XSD `xsd sample.xsd /outputDir:XmlSerialization /c`
- a `.cs` file should be generated, verify it

  - I needed to fix the XSD manually because i.e. *SecurityGroup.SecurityUser* was generated as a 2-dim array
- use the auto-generated classes in your project / script
- create a XmlSerializer - see [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) - and deserialize the XML string, access the data afterwards

```cs
SecurityGroups deserialized;
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(SecurityGroups));
using (var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlData))
{
    deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as SecurityGroups;
}
```

- see my manually fixed XSD [here](http://pastebin.com/09rZM6Pd), verified working with your sample data

Comment: thank you, do you think you can show an example? I have looked at Microsoft and not understanding

Comment: @JamTay317 updated to show how to use XSD tool and the XmlSerializer

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i still don't understand.  This xml can very from time to time and I don't want to have to do this all manually every time, I was want to do this all programmatic. can i format the xml data using xsd.exe? if so, how? why cant i just use serializer? can i use this for approach for more than one stored procedure?

Comment: Does your XML schema vary or your XML data? Your question uses an implicit schema, but a schema nonetheless.

Comment: well both will change. I am going to use one for SecurityUsers and SecurityRegions

Comment: I have found the issue in my code. i will post here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was that i was passing the entire xml into the `ConvertXmlToClass<T>` method. I have fixed this and below is the working code.

```
public class AdminManager : IAdminService
{
    public IEnumerable<SecurityGroup> SecurityGroups()
    {
        IEnumerable<SecurityGroup> list = null;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (var c = new FMContext())
        {
            var xmlData = c.Database.SqlQuery<string>("AllSecurtyUsersProc").FirstOrDefault();
            if (xmlData != null)
            {
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);
                list = ConvertXmlToClass<SecurityGroup>(xmlDoc, "/SecurityGroups/SecurityGroup");
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ConvertXmlToClass<T>(XmlDocument doc, string nodeString)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        var xmlNodes = doc.SelectNodes(nodeString);
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
        {
            var item = GetNewItem<T>(node);
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static T GetNewItem<T>(XmlNode node)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var item = new T();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            var propertyName = property.Name;
            object value = null;
            if (IsEnumerable(property))
            {
                value = GetNodeCollectionValue(property, node);
            }
            else
            {
                value = GetNodeValue(node, propertyName);
            }
            if (value != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType), null);
            }

        }
        return item;
    }

    private static object GetNodeCollectionValue(PropertyInfo property, XmlNode node)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var itemType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var xml = node.InnerXml;
        if (xml.Contains(property.Name))
        {
            var start = xml.IndexOf($"<{property.Name}>");
            var length = xml.IndexOf($"</{property.Name}>") - start + ($"</{property.Name}>").Length;
            xml = xml.Substring(start, length);
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            if (itemType != null)
            {
                var type = typeof(AdminManager);
                var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ConvertXmlToClass");
                if (methodInfo != null)
                {
                    var method = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(itemType);
                    if (method != null)
                    {
                        object[] args = { doc, $"/{property.Name}/{itemType.Name}" };
                        object result = method.Invoke(null, args);
                        var r = result as IEnumerable<object>;
                        return r;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    private static bool IsEnumerable(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var type = property.PropertyType;
        return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsGenericType;
    }

    private static object GetNodeValue(XmlNode node, string nodeName)
    {
        if (node[nodeName] != null)
        {
            var i = node[nodeName].InnerText;
            return i;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else!